# Serverless: Deplyment error S3 Bucket already exists in stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to deploy a serverless project which has s3 bucket creation cloudformation in the serverless.yml file, but the problem is when I tried to deploy, it says the s3 bucket already exists and failing the deployment.

I know s3 bucket name should be globally unique, and I am damn sure it is a unique name that I am using, even if changed to something else, it still says the same.

the cloudformation stack it says the s3 bucket exists is actually the newly created stack, not sure how to fix this issue. can anyone help me out with this issue and tell me how to fix the deployment issue and the cause for the issue :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - in my case it seems to be related to an event that references the S3 bucket, as when I have just the bucket creation but not the event the error is not occurring.

Comment: Can you share the template?

Comment: can you share how is your serverless.yml?

Comment: If the S3 Bucket does not have unique name, you will also get the error, more info: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-error-bucket-already-exists

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue I had was, for one of the lambdas I had the above-mentioned bucket as the `event source`, so when some bucket is added as event source **it actually creating that bucket as well**, therefore when it runs the actual creation related cloudformation it is saying the bucket already exists.

So I fixed it by only keeping the event source and removed the actual declaration of that bucket.

Comment: After 1 hr of scratching my head, I landed on the same conclusion. It's a nasty little caveat.

Comment: I lost the whole day looking for it. It seems more like be a bug to me, the framework should warn or throw an error, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

If you add `existing: true` to the S3 config in your `serverless.yml` file it won't try to create the S3 bucket like the below:-

```
funcName:
    handler: handler
    events:
        -   s3:
                bucket: 'my-bucket-name'
                events: s3:ObjectCreated:*
                existing: true
                rules:
                    -   suffix: .pdf
                    -   prefix: documents
```

Comment: I tried! It doesn't work.

Comment: this property doesn't exist

Comment: It worked for me for `frameworkVersion: '3'`

Answer (score 6):

Anything involving CloudFormation (or any other infrastructure-in-code) is fussy, and the error messages can mislead, meaning there are a ton of things that can cause this problem (see issues on GitHub like [this one](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6923)).

But in my experience, the most common causes of these kind of problems are **are not the pre-existing bucket**, but problems with AWS credentials, permissions, or region that give misleading error messages. To fix these, or at least rule them out:

1. Make sure your `serveless.yml` is set to the region you already deployed the stack in. Example:

```
custom:
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2
```

2. Override any latent credentials from, for example, `~/.aws/credentials`, by explicitly setting your credentials in the shell you'll use to deploy. Example from the [Serverless docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials#use-an-existing-aws-profile):

```sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your access key here>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<your access secret here.
```

3. Make sure those AWS credentials have [the roles and permissions they need](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials/).

But, as I mentioned, CloudFormation is fussy. There may be other problems to solve, but try these first. You may try them and still be beating your head against the wall, but it'll more likely be the *right* wall. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me. In my case, my profile region was set to a different region then the one I was trying to deploy to. Very misleading error message indeed.

Comment: infrastructure-in-code is so fussy!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Conditional statements and pass them as a Parameter to create the bucket or not

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  EnvType:
    Description: Environment type.
    Default: test
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - prod
      - test
    ConstraintDescription: must specify prod or test.
Conditions:
  CreateProdResources: !Equals 
    - !Ref EnvType
    - prod
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0ff8a91507f77f867
  MountPoint:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment'
    Condition: CreateProdResources
    Properties:
      InstanceId: !Ref EC2Instance
      VolumeId: !Ref NewVolume
      Device: /dev/sdh
  NewVolume:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Volume'
    Condition: CreateProdResources
    Properties:
      Size: 100
      AvailabilityZone: !GetAtt 
        - EC2Instance
        - AvailabilityZone
```

Follow the sample condition flow to decide wheather to create a resource or not.
[See this for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html)

Answer (score 1):

When deploying, the BucketName must be unique across all regions. So if anyone has already created a bucket with "local-bucket-dev," it will throw

```
 An error occurred: AttachmentsBucket - local-bucket-dev already 
 exists.
```

Try to just the BucketName to be unique.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the name you chose for the bucket is not a reserved name in AWS. I had same problem with `BucketName: 'analytics-s3-bucket'`
Changed the name and everything is fine