# S3 bucket already existing error - even after manually deleted it from aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless, serverless-framework

Am totally new to this serverless and AWS. am trying to create a S3 bucket using serverless

my serverless.yml file looks like this

```
service: s3-file-uploader 

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2

custom:
  fileUploadBucketName: ${self:service}-bucket-${self:provider.stage} 

resources:
  Resources:
    FileBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.fileUploadBucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
```

for the first time when I run `serverless deploy` it worked, but thereafter I have deleted the bucket manually from aws and try to redeploy it. It shows me this error

```
 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------

  An error occurred: FileBucket - s3-file-uploader-bucket-dev already exists.

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              14.18.0
     Framework Version:         2.72.1
     Plugin Version:            5.5.4
     SDK Version:               4.3.0
     Components Version:        3.18.2
```

it says bucket with `s3-file-uploader-bucket-dev` this name already exists but there is no bucket with this name inside aws s3.
even though it gives this error, also creates a bucket with the name of `s3-file-uploader-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-1aucnojnjl618` but this is not the name I have given in the serverlesss.yml file it should be like `s3-file-uploader-bucket-dev` and in the `cloudFormation` there is a stack created with the name `s3-file-uploader-dev` and its status is `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE`.

Why it's showing the above-mentioned error and at the same time creating a bucket with a different name? it's confusing that give an error and create a bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bucket names are globally unique. You can read about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingBucket.html) and about deleting a bucket [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/delete-bucket.html). If the name has not been taken already by someone else, you need to wait for a "while" to reuse the same name. The time taken is unknown(afaik).

Comment: for clarification, as Bucket names are globally unique, is that mean two different AWS accounts cant create a bucket with the same name?

Comment: @AthavanT, yes exactly. Once a bucket e.g "my-bucket-007" is created, no one else can create a bucket with the same name (my-bucket-007) untill that bucket has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

It can take several hours for a bucket name to become available again.

So, either choose a different bucket name or wait a little longer until it becomes available again.

Comment: for clarification, as Bucket names are globally unique, is that mean two different AWS accounts cant create a bucket with the same name?

Comment: That is correct. Bucket names are unique throughout AWS globally across all AWS Accounts. This is because buckets can be accessed by a common URL format (`bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com`) regardless of where the bucket is located and which account created it.

Answer (score 1):

I've lost some time with a similar error, but the name was not the reason, the reason was adding an event triggered by s3 and having the s3 bucket definition in the same serverless.yml, as pointed here.

[thread with detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086311/serverless-deplyment-error-s3-bucket-already-exists-in-stack)